# Rename a file in PHP folder, not php root

Tags: php, file, ftp, directory, rename

I have a PHP script which I use to rename a file on the FTP server root.

I need to change this to rename the file in a directory on the FTP root.

current working
rename file in root to despgoods.csv

desired working
rename file in root/despgoods/despgoods.csv

My PHP script is:

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.ftpserver.co.za";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$targetname = "DespGoods.csv";
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '');
if (!$contents) {
    echo 'No Files Present on Server: <br/> ';
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
$filename = $contents[0];
if ($filename == "despGoods.csv") {
    echo 'DespGoods already exists, no need to rename: <br/> ';
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
    ftp_rename($conn_id, $filename, $targetname);
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    echo "1 available file renamed to DespGoods.csv <br>";
}
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help as always,

Regards,
Ryan

Comment: You want to move a file from `/` to `root/despgoods/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php

or

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, 'despgoods');
$filename = $contents[0];
if ($filename == "despGoods.csv") {
    echo 'DespGoods already exists, no need to rename: <br/> ';
} else {
    ftp_rename($conn_id, 'despgoods/'.$filename, 'despgoods/'.$targetname);
    echo "1 available file renamed to DespGoods.csv <br>";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

P.S. What `mysql_error()` doing in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.ftpserver.co.za";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$targetdir= "despgoods"; //target directory under which file is to be modified
$targetname = "DespGoods.csv";
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $targetdir);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '');
if (!$contents) {
    echo 'No Files Present on Server: <br/> ';
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
$filename = $contents[0];
if ($filename == "despGoods.csv") {
    echo 'DespGoods already exists, no need to rename: <br/> ';
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
    ftp_rename($conn_id, $filename, $targetname);
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    echo "1 available file renamed to DespGoods.csv <br>";
}
```

Also check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php